# Fast writing bytearray to file

Tags: c#, arrays

I use `_FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, _ByteArray.Length);` to write a bytearray to a file. I noticed that's very slow.
I read a line from a text file, convert it to a bytearray and then need to write it to a new (large > 500 Mb) file. Please some advice to speed up the write process.

Comment: Define slow? Read and write from separate disks, use SSDs.

Comment: I suggest a bit more detail. Where is it slow - writing of the file, converting to bytearray, or you don't know as you've not separated these.  I suggest you put in a bit more code.

Comment: So... you're reading one line at a time, converting it to an array of bytes, then writing those bytes to another file? What are you doing that's different from an OS file copy operation?

Answer (score 1):

`FileStream.Write` is basically what there is. It's *possible* that using a `BufferedStream` would help, but unlikely.

If you're *really* reading a single line of text which, when encoded, is 500MB then I wouldn't be surprised to find that most of the time is being spent performing encoding. You should be able to test that by doing the encoding and then throwing away the result.

Assuming the "encoding" you're performing is just `Encoding.GetBytes(string)`, you might want to try using a `StreamWriter` to wrap the `FileStream` - it may work better by tricks like repeatedly encoding into the same array before writing to the file.

If you're actually reading a line *at a time* and appending that to the file, then:

- Obviously it's best if you keep both the input stream and output stream open throughout the operation. Don't repeatedly read and then write.
- You *may* get better performance using multiple threads or possibly asynchronous IO. This will partly depend on whether you're reading from and writing to the same drive.
- Using a `StreamWriter` is probably still a good idea.

Additionally when creating the file, you *may* want to look at using a constructor which accepts a [`FileOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx). Experiment with the available options, but I suspect you'll want `SequentialScan` and *possibly* `WriteThrough`.

Comment: Each line in the text file contains one value in plain text (32 characters). I read one line at a time, use Encoding.GetBytes(string) to convert each value to a byte array and then write the byte arry to the new file (import another app). Open en close once for both files. If i use StreamWriter to write as 'text' it's much faster.

Comment: _FileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

Comment: @Robertico: Right - in that case I suggest you use StreamWriter :) Why would you *not* use StreamWriter, given that it does the encoding for you?

Comment: I noticed that writing a byte array one by one is the delaying factor. I'm not so experienced, so how can i join my byte arrays (e.g. 1000 at once) and write them to my file using FileStream ? I would appreciate an example.

Comment: @Robertico: Are you sure it's *writing* them rather than *creating* them? `FileStream` already buffers, so it shouldn't be a problem. You could *try* wrapping the `FileStream` in a big `BufferedStream` (or giving `FileStream` a bigger buffer to start with) but I'm not sure it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

If your writing nothing but Byte arrays, have you tried using BinaryWriter's Write method? Writing in bulk would probably also help with the speed. Perhaps you can read each line, convert the string to its bytes, store those bytes for a future write operation (i.e in a List or something), and every so often (after reading x lines) write a chunk to the disk.

BinaryWriter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143302.aspx